# External ui-grid-menu-button?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

There is another stack overflow question at the following url however it happens to be a year old with zero answers:

[External ui-grid-menu-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590471/external-ui-grid-menu-button)

Basically I need to find a way to separate ui-grid-menu-button from the top right of the table and position it somewhere else. I can't seem to find any documentation on this, i'm looking for any work arounds or a hackish solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved this problem.

#### Css to hide the original button

I wrote the purpose of every line in the comments. I have to hide the original button and, because the menu is automagically opened right under that button and I want the menu in the top-right corner, I have to reset the height of the button (see my final result). The position of the opened grid menu could be a problem if you don't want it in the top-left or top-right corner of the table.

```
.ui-grid-menu-button {
    border: none;               // hide button
    background: transparent;    // hide button
}
.ui-grid-menu-button .ui-grid-icon-container {
    visibility: hidden;         // hide button
    height: 0;                  // menu in top-right corner
    margin-top: 0;              // menu in top-right corner
}
```

#### Html of my custom button

```
<div
    ng-if="myUiGridOptions.enableGridMenu"
    ng-click="gridApi.grid.gridMenuScope.toggleMenu()">
    <!-- menu icon -->
</div>
```

The `gridApi` object is the api of ui-grid, obtainable in this way

```
myUiGridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) => {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
};
```

---

## My final result

[image: Screen with closed menu]
[image: Screen with opened menu]